# The given range isn't in document, when trying to add a link in summernote

Tags: javascript, summernote

I get an error in my Chrome console, whet I try to add a link to a text with Summernote. Summernote is a part of a Bootstrap theme. The error occurs here:

```
this.select = function () {
  var nativeRng = nativeRange();
  if (agent.isW3CRangeSupport) {
    var selection = document.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      selection.removeAllRanges();
    }
    selection.addRange(nativeRng);
  } else {
    nativeRng.select();
  }
};
```

at the line `selection.addRange(nativeRng);` I tried this solution, by adding `dialogsInBody: true` to `summernote()` function, but it didn't help me. Any ideas of what is wrong with the editor? Thank you ahead.

**EDIT:** I've found that it happens only if `airMode` is set to `false`. If `airMode: true` - it works, but the editor is displayed differently.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it in Angular 7 by adding below code.

```
@ViewChild('editor') editor: Editor;
setTimeout(() => {
this.editor.writeValue(data);
this.editor.quill.setSelection(null, data.length, null);
}, 100);
```